# PrintPage draw string not showing C#

Tags: c#, graphics, printdocument

So I am trying to draw a string in a loop in the `PrintPage` event of a `PrintDocument`:

```
for (int c = 0; c < currentwords; c++)
{
    // index is a global int that starts at 0 and f9 is a font with size 9
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(allitems[index], f9, Brushes.Black, new Point(100, 100));
    // I used new Point(100, 100) for debugging purposes but normally I would
    // do some calculating to see where it is to be printed
    index++;
}
```

It seems all normal, and the debugger shows that it gets run when I use a breakpoint but when I display the document in a `PrintPreviewDialog` it does not show up. `allitems[index]` **does** contain a value and I am not sure why it is not displaying. I am printing other strings and rectangles *outside* the loop and they show up in the dialog. If anyone could help me please post here, Thanks!

Edit:

Here are the graphics modes/rendering hints:

```
ev.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
ev.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
ev.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
ev.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
ev.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Edit 2:

Alright, so I used:

```
ev.Graphics.DrawString(allitems[0], f9, Brushes.Black, new Point(100, 100));
for (int c = 0; c < currentwords; c++)
{
    // index is a global int that starts at 0 and f9 is a font with size 9
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(allitems[index], f9, Brushes.Black, new Point(100, 100));
    // I used new Point(100, 100) for debugging purposes but normally I would
    // do some calculating to see where it is to be printed
    index++;
}
```

And only the `DrawString` outside the loop was being displayed but the loop should work and the code is being run.

Comment: That snippet doesn't help us help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to post really, the only other thing that involves the issue is that at the start I am setting the modes and rendering hints for the graphics. I will add it into the post.

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you tried using different fonts, brushes? Does `ev.Graphics.DrawString(allitems[0], f9, Brushes.Black, new Point(100, 100));` work? Is the point definitely within the page bounds?

Comment: I tried: `ev.Graphics.DrawString(allitems[0], new Font("Segoe", 30), Brushes.Red, new Point(ev.MarginBounds.X + 50, ev.MarginBounds.Y + 50));` but it still does not show up. I also added more to the post, please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the problem was if I am drawing more than once in a for loop like so:

```
for (int c = 0; c < currentwords; c++)
{
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(allitems[index], f9, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(allqty[index], f9, Brushes.Black, new Point(200, 200);
    ev.Graphics.DrawString((allprices[index].Contains('$')) ? allprices[index] : "$" + allprices[index], f9, Brushes.Black, 300, 300);
}
```

It would not show any of them at all. To fix this I have to have each `DrawString` method in a different loop, not sure why it doesn't work other-wise.

Answer (score -1):

Chaneg the loop control variable to 'index'. Your mistake is that you are not using the loop control variable for the loop.